# Replace existing activity on top of back stack with a new instance of it

Tags: android

If I use an intent to open an activity but an instance of that activity is already on the top of the activity stack, how can I replace the current instance with the new instance? Is there a flag for this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Try this flag, I think this does not do exactly what you say but definitely close.

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Comment: This just bring the old activity to the front of the stack if it's not in the front already, but I want to replace it with a new instance of its class. So if the stack is A,B,C then I want to replace C with a new instance of class C.

Comment: Intent.FLAG_REPLACE would be great

Comment: looks like deleting old activity is not an easy task , i have edited , but still it does not do exactly

Answer (score 0):

Try LaunchModes to be `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` and that will make only a single instance. So if you create a new instance of an activity, then it'll open the previous instance just replace the difference between a new and an old one.

Comment: I want to replace the one on the top, not reuse it.